# Where is the standard library in python virtual environment?

Tags: python, conda, virtual-environment

I'm using Ubuntu system with python 3.5 installed by default.

When I use the `venv` module to create virtual environment, I can't find the standard library in my virtual environment but only the binary file for python interpreter. However I can import standard library modules in my python script when I switch to use this virtual environment.

So how does `venv` work? Does the newly created virtual environment just use the standard library of the system python? If so, what if I want to create a completely self-contained virtual environment? Is it possible to achieve this by the `venv` module? By the way, I used `conda` before. `conda` can create virtual environment with python different with the system version. Can `venv` do this job?

Comment: `import sys; print(sys.path)` this will show where python is looking for all the modules. You will always get pythons standard modules but you may or may not have access to the installed system modules - that's part of the config of the virtual environment.

Comment: @AChampion Yes the virtual environment created by `venv` looks standard library module in the global system python installation. I think it is strange for `venv` to behave this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because `venv` uses the systems standard library. it will be a problem if you update actual Python because version mismatch can happen there. Take a look at the following link you will get more information.
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/

Comment: So, within the virtual environment, we have a standalone python interpreter and standalone site-package, but a standard library dependent on system python. Right?

Comment: yes, exactly. so, if you update your Python, then your code developed in virtual env might face version issue

Comment: I agree with you. I think it is strange to create a virtual environment like this.  Why doesn't `venv` just create a standalone standard library within the virtual environment to avoid the potential version issue? Maybe the development team has a special consideration for the behavior of `venv` module?