# My library cannot find the subdependency inside the venv

Tags: python, python-venv, python-poetry

I'm not understanding how my Python script and library are using the venv. I create the library with `python -m venv .venv`, then `poetry add` everything, and finally `poetry publish`. Therefore the library contains its own `.venv`. On the other hand, for my script I do `python -m venv .venv` , then `pip install <library>` into the script's own `.venv`. I don't believe this `poetry` vs. `pip` difference should be causing my issue, but I'm highlighting it for context.

So I run the script with `.venv\Scripts\python.exe my_script.py`. Afaik, that's all that's needed to run my script inside its venv, ie. I don't actually have to run `.venv/Scripts/activate` or anything else. This appears to work fine, because I can see my script is using the library installed in its venv. **However, the library itself is not using the venv's `python.exe` or its libraries.**

I've only noticed this now due to an exception that happened today. Please ignore the `PermissionError` itself, it's actually expected because today the destination file was open at the time. However, it revealed what I believe is either an issue with my setup or a misunderstanding on my part:

```
2022-03-07 09:13:36,364 ERROR   [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\path\\to\\file\\I\\wanted\\to\\overwrite.pdf'     (files.py:36)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\<user>\<project folder>\.venv\lib\site-packages\<library>\file_system\files.py", line 33, in copy_file
    shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 266, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '\\\\path\\to\\file\\I\\wanted\\to\\overwrite.pdf'
```

As you can see, my script correctly resorts to the library in the `.venv` (in fact this library has never been installed system-wide so it really has no choice). My library uses `shutil` to copy the file. However, it is not resorting to the `shutil` inside the script's `.venv`, but rather the system-wide Python installation, as seen here:

```
File "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 266, in copyfile
```

I suppose that since `shutil` is part of Python's standard library, it found the general one before it found the `shutil` in the venv? Is there a way to tell my script/library to use the `shutil` in the `.venv`? Is there even an `shutil` in the `.venv`?? When I browse `.venv\Lib\site-packages`, I don't see any `shutil` there, but then again I don't see any of Python's standard modules either (eg. os, logging, etc.) so I'm not surprised. But how do I force my script to use the `shutil` in its `.venv` instead of the `shutil` from the system's Python? Is it a matter of reordering or removing the system Python from PATH?

Thanks

Comment: Seems correct to me. The standard library is not copied in the virtual environment. The `python.exe` in the virtual environment needs and uses the standard library of the Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment. This is normal behavior.

Comment: Ohh ok, I didn't know that! Thanks for confirming. I probably should've googled that first, eg. this corroborates what you're saying: eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853321/where-is-the-standard-library-in-python-virtual-environment

It's unintuitive since the idea of a venv is to be self-contained and avoid issues with the system Python/libraries. But if this is expected then ok.

If you copy-paste your comment as a reply, I can select it as the answer. Although really now my post kind of feels like a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like normal behavior to me. The standard library is not copied in the virtual environment. The `python.exe` in the virtual environment needs and uses the standard library of the Python interpreter used to create the virtual environment.

> Each virtual environment has its own Python binary (allowing creation of environments with various Python versions) and can have its own independent set of installed Python packages in its site directories, but shares the standard library with the base installed Python.

-- ["*Abstract*" section of *PEP 405*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#abstract)

See also:

- [Where is the standard library in python virtual environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853321/where-is-the-standard-library-in-python-virtual-environment)